# Looking for (preferaby free) sofware that can pan an input signal while recording to a stereo track

Tags: audio-recording, software, panning, input, windows-10

To explain - I am an actor. I like to learn my lines by recording myself reading everyone else's lines on the right track, and all my lines on the left track.
That way, on playback, I can mute the left track and listen to the right track, saying my lines in the gaps (and unmute left when I forget).

I used to have a cumbersome bit of kit that would do this with the flick of a switch, but surely there must be a recording program that will allow me to pan the input hard R/L without it.

I would like to accomplish this hard input panning with one or, at worst, two clicks/keystrokes while I am recording.

I have Audacity, but I just can't work out how to do it with that. If anyone knows of a preferably free Windows program that will do this, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: Having read your question, the answer and comments several times I still don't get, what you DO. So I suggest to EDIT your question and add one or two scenarios of what you DO w.r.t. voice recording or replay in *generic terms*. Then it may become more evident, what you are after. Thanks (What I'd like to understand are the various roles of live spoken, replayed and and recorded voices. If it helps, feel free to add a (manual) sketch how they develop in time. Like a screenplay as graphics.)

Comment: Can I also ask for some clarity, Dave? I can't think of a solution unless I understand. I get stuck on the ***"while I am recording"*** bit. If you'd have said "while I'm listening", I'd completely get it. Why do you want to mute *while recording* your lines/other lines/stage dirs? In my mind, you've already recorded your lines at this stage, right? You just need to say them if you remember them, or unmute the left if you don't. Why are you re-recording at this stage?

Comment: I think we've done this to death, but to try and clarify again - let's forget about the whole acting stuff, that's just to explain *why* I want to do it. What I want to do is : open two tracks; start recording my voice onto both tracks (as standard); while speaking press a button (or two) that causes the sound to be recorded on only one track; while speaking press a button (or two) that causes my voice to be recorded on only the other track. However it seems that none of the common sound processing programs will do this, so I shall go back to my mechanical switch. Thanks to all for trying.

Comment: I've edited your question, so it's easier to understand what you want. I also added an answer, because you *can* do it with some good input routing - there are other ways to do it, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in audacity with one click per track.

Open your stereo file. Right click in the left bar & select Split Stereo Track.

[image]

Then you can click one or other Solo button to mute the other track, or Mute button to mute the current one. Or key commands Shift/S or Shift/U.

[image]

Comment: Or create two (mono) tracks, pan one to the left and the other one to the right. Solo your track, which will mute (all) the other.

Comment: @MS-SPO That's exactly what he did lol

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but this switches tracks while playing. I want to switch tracks *while recording*

Comment: That really wasn't clear from your question. It looks like you can do the same in record, but I haven't tested it on any real input.

Comment: "there must be a recording program that will allow me to mute each track separately with one or, at worst, two clicks/keystrokes while I am recording". Fairly clear :). I spent a good deal of time trying to find a way to do it with Audacity and failed, so if you or anyone can do it I'd be really impressed (and grateful)

Comment: Yeah, I just never assumed someone would be trying to rehearse & engineer at the same time. Have you tried my suggestion at least?

Comment: Tetsujin: hanks for trying on this, I appreciate it, but I think we have a misunderstanding. I need to make a recording which is effectively "stereo", in that it has some parts which are right-side only (everyone else's lines) and some parts which are left-side only (my lines) and some bits which are both (stage directions). I then copy this to a CD (or other medium) and, for example, play it in the car while driving to work.

Comment: Initially I play it normally, while I learn the lines. Once I know them I turn the balance to the far right so I can no longer hear my lines, and take my cues from what is coming out of the right speaker. Switching tracks at playback time is not what it's about. I can do it by recording the two tracks separately, leaving gaps where the other track will go, but that means going through twice, and I just thought there must be an easier way.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is a three-track recording, you, them, directions; panned left, right, centre. The 'mute button' is a red herring, as is 'being able to do it whilst recording'. You can then just pan it in playback as you do already. If none of these three parts ever overlaps, you could record all at once in mono, then manually split to three tracks to set up panning, export as stereo. I don't see any way, short of a multi-bus external sound board, to do this 'automatically'.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I'd concluded. I used to use an actual physical switch that I built myself that I plugged the microphone into that would switch out each channel, but it doesn't work very well with modern computers. The real question is whether anyone knows of an alternative to Audacity that supports the feature on record. Ho Hum. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Yeah, after reading this convo, I still don't get it lol. Unless you're using the wrong words to describe what you're doing(no offence :)). It seems like a good idea, just to play back and pan with balance. Further than that; a mind-reading device that knows when you've learnt the lines and so mutes automatically? Is that what you're looking for? I just formulated that live lol. Oh wait, is that the re-recording bit? Re-record with muted sections on-the-fly?

Comment: :). Hi N00dles - none taken. I think you may have got it. It's quite simple really. Open a 2-channel recording. Press Record and say "blah blah" and it records onto both channels - so far as normal. Now I want to press a button and the recording continues ("blah blah") but only on ONE channel. Then press a button and the recording continues ("blah blah") but only on THE OTHER channel. Play back and I hear "Blah blah" in the centre, then "Blah blah" on the right, then "Blah blah" on the left.

Comment: Now we've got right down to what's actually required, I think you just *don't want to be doing this live*. If you're recording a table reading/early rehearsal/blocking etc, then you want everybody to be concentrating on the pacing, not on whether someone's pressing the right button to send this line to that track, that line to the other, stage direction to both. You really should just do this in post. Every time you press the wrong button, you'll have to interrupt the rehearsal to get everybody to go back a bit & start over.

Comment: Oh dear, we're still misunderstanding the problem. This doesn't involve anyone else, it's just a way of getting my lines onto a recording for my use so I can play it in my car/on my stereo. I don't think I can express it any more succinctly than I did above for N00dles. I just want a recording program to record my voice that allows me to record onto one channel at a time, switching between channels while recording. It's really not complicated, it's just that Audacity can't do it.

Comment: Sorry, but this has been like pulling teeth, an exercise in mind reading. We only now are told *you're* doing all the parts. Anyway, just because *you* think this shouldn't be complicated doesn't mean it isn't. I can't even do this in the full-blown Cubase Pro with only a single input bus. I can flip which track records but not with exclusivity. Audio recorders are just not designed with this kind of task in mind. This is something that would just be done in post.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. How many people are involved is really irrelevant. Two tracks - record on just one, press a button, record on just the other. Anyway, FWIW I've just tried with Cakewalk and that won't do it either. I guess I go back to the mechanical switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed pan on recording or "mute recording on alternate tracks" as you originally put it.

It can be easy, or difficult, depending on the software and your technical knowledge, but logically, what you need is this:

```
Input(1 Ch) -> [Method of splitting/fading between two channels] -> 
Recording Tracks (2 Ch; where Ch1 -> Out L and Ch2 -> Out R)
```

Then on playback, you will be able to pan L/R as you desire.

So… basically you need an input panning control. And as this is not often required, you would need software with good routing capabilities.

**Audacity**
I tried this in Audacity, and as it's just a simple audio recorder/editor, it is very limited in routing capabilities. The real-time effects looked promising - it seems all you need is an effect with a pan control and then record to a stereo track - but not only did the panning not work, but none of the effects worked in real-time anyway.

**Cubase**
As I'm away atm, I tried it on a Cubase 5 install I have on my old laptop. So anyway, this is how I did it in Cubase 5 using the free [ASIO4ALL](https://www.asio4all.org/) ASIO driver (it should hopefully transfer to other software):

- Firstly, I created two mono input buses in `Devices` -> `VST Connections`
  -> `Inputs` called `Mono In` and `Mono In 2`, both using the same input as a source (I used my laptop mic in this example).
  [image]
  This will create two input channels in the mixer by the same names
  [image]
- I then created two mono audio tracks. On the first, I set input to `Mono In` and output to `Left - Stereo Out`. On the second, I set input to `Mono In 2` and output to `Right - Stereo Out`.
  So the first track will output it's recorded signal to the left channel and the second to the right. Simples!
  [image]
  [image]
- I then Armed both tracks and recorded. Then, using the mute buttons on the channels `Mono In` and `Mono In 2` on the mixer, I could effectively switch between left and right channels while recording.
  (I also renamed the channels and tracks to make it easier to understand - `Mono In` => `My Lines`, `Mono In 2` => `Other Lines`, `Audio 01` => `Left`, `Audio 02` => `Right`)
  [image]

Furthermore, you could probably create a macro or key command that would allow you to make the mute button changes with simple keystrokes.

So there you go, one way of doing it. When exported, this will create a stereo file that you can pan/mute L or R on playback exactly as you wanted. You should be able to transfer this or a similar process to other DAWs with a little bit of knowledge.

Comment: Wow, N00dles, thank you for putting so much effort into this (at Christmas too!), and also for fixing up my original question - as I am not a sound engineer obviously I was not getting the terminology quite right which was causing confusion. I am still surprised that what seems (to me) such a simple requirement is so complicated to achieve, but obviously it is just something that a "proper" sound engineer would never want/need to do. I will give your CuBase solution a go - hopefully once set up it will be simpler than my home-made 2-p-3-w switch (+ additional gadgetry) :). Happy New Year

Comment: No problem, Dave! Yeah, ideally, in modern recording, input signals are recorded clean then edited and processed later. Happy new year.